# multiple check box selection in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, multi-select, parameters, form-for

I'm new to rails and web programming in general and have searched SO for an answer to this but couldn't find what I was looking for. This is one of my first rails projects so please go easy on me. :)

I am trying to update a join table that resolves a many to many relationship between a workouts table, and an exercises table.

the params hash I'm receiving from my select box submission looks like this

[params hash on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgiJj.png)

I'm trying to access the ids in those params, but with no success. I keep getting the error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

My models look like this

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :muscle_group
    has_many :workout_exercises
    has_many :workouts, through: :workout_exercises

end


class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :workout_exercises
    has_many :exercises, through: :workout_exercises
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_exercises
end


class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :exercise
    belongs_to :workout
end
```

and my WorkoutsController looks like this

```
 def edit
        @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
        @workoutExercise = WorkoutExercise.new
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.js {@exercise = Exercise.where(muscle_group_id: params[:idmg])}
   end
end


   def update
        @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    params[:workout_exercises[:exercises]].each do |e|
        if !e.empty?
            @workout.workoutexercise.build(:exercise_id => e)
        end
    end
```

the form looks like this

```
    <h3>here is where our exercises will go</h3>

    <% if !@exercise.nil? %>
    <%= form_for(@workout) do |w| %>

      <%= fields_for :workout_exercises, @workout_exercises do |we| %>
      <%= we.label :exercises %><br>
      <%= we.collection_check_boxes(:exercises, @exercise, :id, :name) do |ec| %>
        <%= ec.object.name%>
        <%= ec.check_box %><br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<%= w.submit "Add", class: "pure_button" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm using the edit and update methods if the WorkoutController to update the workout_exercises table. The idea is to populate the join table with the id of the current workout, and with the id's of each of the id's passed in from the checkbox collection.

The form above is a partial that is rendered with an ajax call to the edit action in the WorkoutController to update the checkbox selection based on a "body part" dropdown. (it shows all the exercises associated with a muscle group)

Also any advice on how to do this a better way is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance. Again this is my first project so any other tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

after working on this for hours I realized I needed to call save after the build method.

I also realized I was iterating through my params hash incorrectly

updating the update action in the WorkoutsController fixed my problem.

```
def update
        @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
        params[:workout_exercises][:exercises].each do |e|
            if !e.empty?
                we = @workout.workout_exercises.build(:exercise_id => e)
                we.save
            end
        end
```